Setting values of new column df.loc[:,'newcol']=1
I'd like to create a new column this way:
df['newcol']=1

I get this error: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
When using the suggestion:
df.loc[:,'newcol']=1

I keep getting the same error...
What am I doing wrong? And no I'm not interested in copying this dataframe with .copy. I just want to add a new column to this df.

Most likely your issue comes from something that you did before. Try df = df.copy() to solve the issue.

Can you share more of your code of how you go here ?

yeah my df came from this df=main_df.query(), so I guess this is the issue.
